# Palm Centro not even appearing on desktop

Tags: mount, xubuntu, jpilot

Background: I'm trying to set up my dad's new installation of Xubuntu 12.10 (I finally got him to switch from Windows :-D) so he can sync his Palm Centro on his computer. I installed J-Pilot, but the problem is that his palm isn't even showing up anywhere on the computer. When it's plugged in, it lit up and began to charge when I told it to try and sync with the computer, but it failed the sync and Xubuntu still doesn't recognize it.

Question: Does anyone know how I can get his Palm to be recognized by Xubuntu?

Comment: Thx a lot! This has worked-around my .jpilot Palm m505 Handheld synchronization issues on Trusty Tahr Ubuntu 14.04 LTS as of August 2014: jpilot run as root is working fine. You can synchronize Palm / Visor / Treo / Clie with that. Now finding running it as user again...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Palm USB connection works only during a hotsync operation.

So if you installed Jpilot, try clicking both the hotsync button on your Centro and on Jpilot.

If this doesn't sync, open a terminal and type `sudo usermod -a -G dialout username` changing username with your actual username.

Then try syncing again as explained above.

Comment: Will that overwrite what's on the Palm?

Comment: No it won't overwrite anything. It should copy the address book, datebook etc to jpilot.

Comment: That didn't work, although I stumbled on the correct answer. It seems that you don't need to be a part of the dialout group - to test, I created a new user, and tried to sync under sudo, and it started to sync, despite the new user not being a member of the dialout group. Thanks for responding, anyway!

Comment: Being able to sync as your normal user *without* using sudo requires being in the dialout group. I don't think it is a good idea to use jpilot always with sudo. It's an old application which is no longer supported.

Comment: Oh, yeah, that worked. I had added myself to the dialout group using your command earlier, it just hadn't worked the first time; maybe I was just too tired to think clearly...  Thanks so much for helping!