# How to set permissions to use jpilot and synchronize?

Tags: permissions, jpilot

The information and manuals are so bad that I had to discover that I need to sudo to execute

```
pilot-xfer -p usb: -r <directory>
```

successfully in order to restore a Palm handheld connected to a usb port (I don't know which one and can't figure it out)

I also guessed (because the info is terrible) that I had to execute jpilot as root (from the command line) to be able to synchronize later on, from the jpilot GUI.

The problem is that some files are converted to be root files, others aren't, and I don't like the idea of having to execute these things as root.

So I would like to know which group to add my user to, or how to create one so that I can have permission to synchronize elegantly: with the minimum changes/effort.

Answer (score 0):

Type `id` and press Enter. Check whether or not you are a member of the `dialout` group. If not, [add yourself to the group](https://askubuntu.com/a/223575).

Does this work for you?

<sub>(The idea of joining the `dialout` group is discussed in various sources: see, for example, `/usr/share/doc/pilot-link/README.Debian` written by Ben Darnell and Ludovic Rousseau.)</sub>